# PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER in Firebase AuthUI not woiking

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Phone verification in my android application is not working. when i am adding `AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER`, the editor showing that `cannot resolve symbol`. Other verification method like Google or email are working fine.

**Here is the screen-shot for this:**

[image]
**Here is Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nishant.kitchenbook"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your firebaseui version to the latest. Change compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.1' to compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.1.1'